# Log files get reset on the restart of the application instead of appending the new logs to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

```
    import logging
    
    def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.DEBUG):
        l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='w')
        fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    
        l.setLevel(level)
        l.addHandler(fileHandler)
        l.addHandler(streamHandler)
```

I'm trying to write the different logs(levels) to the different files the functionality is working fine but when ever the application is restarted the log files get reset instead of appending the data to it.

```
#method called from the different method
setup_logger('logger', 'login.log')
setup_logger('logger_market', 'transaction.log')

logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
logger_market = logging.getLogger('logger_market')

logger.info(f'Test for the login.log file')
logger_market.info(f'this to test')
```

I'm new to logging in python and the documentation is a bit complex for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need to set `mode`

just use following: `fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)`